# How set version for serverless project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, serverless-framework

I have downgraded serverless to `1.38.0` version via `npm install -g serverless@1.38.0` command. The invokes `npm install` on a folder with the following `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "serverless-defaults",
  "version": "1.6.0",
  "description": "description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/???"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/???"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/???#readme",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "serverless-cf-vars": "^0.3.2",
    "serverless-domain-manager": "3.2.7",
    "serverless-pseudo-parameters": "^2.4.0",
    "serverless-step-functions": "^2.6.0"
  }
}
```

And got:

```
cmd.exe /c "npm install"
npm WARN deprecated superagent@3.8.3: Please note that v5.0.1+ of superagent removes User-Agent header by default, therefore you may need to add it yourself (e.g. GitHub blocks requests without a User-Agent header).  This notice will go away with v5.0.2+ once it is released.

> spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall C:\pah\node_modules\spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> jsonpath@1.0.2 postinstall C:\pah\node_modules\jsonpath
> node lib/aesprim.js > generated/aesprim-browser.js


> serverless@1.53.0 postinstall C:\pah\node_modules\serverless
> node ./scripts/postinstall.js

 +--------------------------------------------------+
 |                                                  |
 |  Serverless Framework successfully installed!    |
 |  To start your first project, run “serverless”.  |
 |                                                  |
 +--------------------------------------------------+

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.0 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 592 packages from 368 contributors and audited 1848 packages in 32.798s
found 0 vulnerabilities


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why does `serverless@1.53.0` appear in logs??? Where `npm` got last serverless version??? Where to specify serverless version which I need?

Answer (score 0):

`serverless-step-functions` [depends directly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-step-functions) on the Serverless Framework. My guess is that it's resolving to the newest compatible version.

Try adding a new entry in your `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "serverless": "1.38.0"
}
```

which should ensure that `serverless-step-functions` won't install a newer version of the framework.